# How to create notification inside an activity in android?

Tags: android, notifications

I have a task in which I have to show `Notification` for an incoming message inside an activity using `BroadcastReceiver` with the address and content on the SMS. Now I have to click in order to insert the values in sms in database. When the task is finished i want it to clear from the activity. Is it possible to create notification for incoming sms inside an Activity?

Comment: yes it is possible. what is the question now ?

Comment: have to show notification for incoming message inside an activity.

Comment: you are asking for code. there are thousand answers on How to generate notification, you just need to understand the way. Btw answer is posted by someone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can Try This no generate your own Notification.

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
private static void generateNotification(Context context) {

    int icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
    long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Notification notification = new Notification(icon, "New Contact Added",
            when);

    String title = context.getString(R.string.app_name);

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);

    // set intent so it does not start a new activity
    notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
            | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

    int iUniqueId = (int) (System.currentTimeMillis() & 0xfffffff);

    PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, iUniqueId,
            notificationIntent, 0);
    notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, "New", intent);
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

    // Play default notification sound
    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;

    // Vibrate if vibrate is enabled
    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
    notificationManager.notify(2, notification);

}
```

Comment: Yes When you will fire Receiver for Message, inside that it will work